# Google API's console an application allowing

Tags: google-oauth

Last year I defined in `Google API's` console an application allowing user to login thru that platform. It worked fine, displaying when logging in the website's name.

It appears that Google changed this and now with the new API's login I am getting some strange text instead of the website's name.

See print screen at [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, google changed the Consent screen setup when they revamped the console.
Go to https://cloud.google.com/console
Click your project name
Click APIs and Auth
Click Consent Screen
Fill out the form and click save